Duplicate PATCH Requests on Single Axios Call in React + Express App, Not Replicated with Postman
I am experiencing a challenging issue with my React (TypeScript) + Node.js/Express application where a single client-side Axios PATCH request results in the server receiving two identical requests spaced about a second apart. This behavior is confirmed by duplicated logs on the server side and results in duplicate database entries when the server performs its intended operations. Importantly, this duplication does not occur when the same request is made from Postman, hinting at a client-side issue.
Client-Side Setup:
Within my React app, I have a SyncWorker component designed to synchronize certain items immediately upon loading. This component is currently as simplified as possible because I intended to build it up step by step. However, even in its most basic form, the issue of duplicated requests already occurs.
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function SyncWorker() {
  const processingIdsRef = useRef<Set<number>>(new Set());

  const syncItems = useCallback(async (unsynced: any[]) => {
    for (const item of unsynced) {
      if (processingIdsRef.current.has(item.id!)) continue;

      processingIdsRef.current.add(item.id!);

      try {
        const response = await axios.patch(
          `${
            import.meta.env.VITE_PUBLIC_SERVER_BASE_URL
          }/ongoing-jobs/configure-device`,
          {
            ongoing_job_id: item.ongoing_job_id,
            type: item.type,
            image_url: item.image_url,
            position_identifier: item.position_identifier,
            serial_number: item.serial_number,
          }
        );
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Failed to update monitor: ", err);
      } finally {
        processingIdsRef.current.delete(item.id!);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsynced: any[] = [
      {
        ongoing_job_id: "ongoing_job_id_424242",
        type: "fan",
        image_url: "www.image-url.com",
        position_identifier: "1.0.0",
        serial_number: "9",
      },
    ];
    syncItems(unsynced).catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  return null;
}

export default SyncWorker;

This component is used in my main App.tsx like so:
// Part of App.tsx
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <ToastContainer />
      <ContextWrapper>
        <SyncWorker />
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            {/* Routes configuration */}
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </ContextWrapper>
    </>
  );
}

Server-Side Simplified Route Handler:
The server-side Express route is also stripped down for debugging purposes. Despite this, the issue of receiving two requests for what should be a single Axios call is evident through duplicate logs, and in a fuller implementation, would result in two database writes.
// Express route in my Node.js server
router.patch("/ongoing-jobs/configure-device", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { position_identifier } = req.body;
    console.log("Configuring device for:", position_identifier); // This logs twice for a single client request
    res.status(200).send("Configuring device for: " + position_identifier);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Failed to update job: ", err.message);
    res.status(500).send({ error: err.message });
  }
});

Noteworthy Observations:

React Strict Mode is Disabled: I have already disabled React Strict Mode in my application.
Behavior Across Environments: This issue replicates both locally and
in the deployed version of the application.
Postman Testing: When simulating the same PATCH request via Postman, the server logs the operation once, as expected, which strongly suggests the duplication originates from the client-side setup.

Seeking Solutions For:
Given these details, I am puzzled as to what could be causing these duplicate PATCH requests from my React app. The fact that Postman's test behaves as expected but the actual app does not is particularly perplexing.

Could this be related to the way Axios or React effects are being used?
Is there a known issue with React or Axios that could lead to such behavior?
Any insights on how to debug or resolve this issue would be immensely valuable


Does this answer your question? Why useEffect running twice and how to handle it well in React?

@Konrad nope. As I've mentioned I've disabled strict mode and the same behavior happens in production as well.
